# Console keep showing angular is not defined

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs I tried implement a simple code using angular but when try to run it in browser it keeps prompting errors in console

This is my code

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="main.controller.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="DriverApp" >
<div ng-controller="MainController" >
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Birthday</th>
            <th>Vehicle</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="driver in drivers">
            <td>{{driver.ranking}}</td>
            <td>{{driver.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{driver.lastName}}</td>
            <td>{{driver.birthday}}</td>
            <td>{{driver.vehicle}}</td>
            <td><a>Open</a></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <form name="MyForm">
        <div id="collapseExample" >
            <br/>
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Rank" ng-model="driver.ranking">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="First name" ng-model="driver.firstName">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" ng-model="driver.lastName">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Birthday" ng-model="driver.birthday">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Vehicle" ng-model="driver.vehicle">
            </div>
            <div>
                <button ng-click="addDriver()">Add</button>

            </div>
            <br/>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And i attached the error as a screen shot below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA5nx.png)

Answer (score 1):

change order of included js files

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.module.js"></script>
<script src="main.controller.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the order of the script files:

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.module.js"></script>
<script src="main.controller.js"></script>
```